# sed: Remove from nth character until crossing keyword in each line

Tags: string, awk, sed

Here, from **37th** character to until crossing the keyword i.e, **<4>** to be removed. Below is the example.

```
<...>-2703  [000] ....    42.930888: msm_vdec_dqbuf: <4> 20:18:45.822999]
<...>-2704  [003] ....    42.940897: create_pkt_cmd_session_ftb: <4> 20:18:45.832999]
```

to

```
<...>-2703  [000] ....    42.930888: 20:18:45.822999]
<...>-2704  [003] ....    42.940897: 20:18:45.832999]
```

I am trying, but somehow didnt get exactly. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.{36}).*<4>/\1/' filename    # -E instead of -r for BSD sed
```

Or with basic regex syntax:

```
sed 's/\(.\{36\}\).*<4>/\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk -F"<4> " '{print substr($0,1,37) $2}' file
<...>-2703  [000] ....    42.930888: 20:18:45.822999]
<...>-2704  [003] ....    42.940897: 20:18:45.832999]
```

Print the first `37` characters then the rest after `<4>`

Comment: @BalamuruganA I did test this on ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 both works fine. `sed` also works on both system.